# How to bypass System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute.IsAuthorized

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

In our server, CORS is already enabled, so that scripts like `ajax` may communicate in our API.  But this is only effective on API that has no `SecureAttribute`

This one is working properly:

```
[CorsPreflightEnabled]
public class DevicesController : ApiController
{
    [CorsEnabled]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Register(DTO::ClientInfo info)
```

While this one is always rejected:

```
[CorsPreflightEnabled]
[Http::Secure]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [CorsEnabled]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool AddClaims(Domain::DTO.UserClaim claim)
```

This is the code for SecureAttribute:

```
public class SecureAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var calltoken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Device"] ?? "";
        var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceCallToken>(calltoken) ?? new DeviceCallToken();

        var cachetoken = new ClientAuthentication().VerifyDevice(token);

        if (cachetoken != null)
        {
            // if a cachetoken was successfully extracted from our records,
            // then store the information into the principal for possible reuse

            var principal = AppPrincipal.Current;
            var identity = principal.Identity as AppIdentity;

            identity.ServiceHeader.SessionId = token.SessionId;
            identity.ServiceHeader.ClientKey = cachetoken.ClientKey;
            identity.ServiceHeader.DeviceCode = cachetoken.DeviceCode;
            identity.ServiceHeader.Merchant = cachetoken.Merchant;

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }

        return cachetoken != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cachetoken.Salt);
    }
}
```

When I call the API using `ajax` the `Method` is set to `OPTIONS` and the value of `calltoken` is always `null`.

Now my question is, how can I bypass checking the security when the method is `OPTIONS`?

I found that, if I try to put values in `calltoken` via breakpoint, the `IsAuthorized` will be called again for the last time, and from there the `Device` header has now value.

I really hope that I explained myself well. If not, I may have to show some images.

**EDIT: Working code**

```
public class SecureAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var calltoken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Device"] ?? "";
        var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceCallToken>(calltoken) ?? new DeviceCallToken();

        var cachetoken = new ClientAuthentication().VerifyDevice(token);

        if (cachetoken != null)
        {
            // if a cachetoken was successfully extracted from our records,
            // then store the information into the principal for possible reuse

            var principal = AppPrincipal.Current;
            var identity = principal.Identity as AppIdentity;

            identity.ServiceHeader.SessionId = token.SessionId;
            identity.ServiceHeader.ClientKey = cachetoken.ClientKey;
            identity.ServiceHeader.DeviceCode = cachetoken.DeviceCode;
            identity.ServiceHeader.Merchant = cachetoken.Merchant;

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
        }
        else
        {
            var originalRequest = actionContext.Request;
            var isCorsRequest = originalRequest.Headers.Contains("Origin");

            if (originalRequest.Method == HttpMethod.Options && isCorsRequest)
            {
                // Allow to penetrate
                return true;
            }
        }

        return cachetoken != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cachetoken.Salt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to bypass the authorisation attribute, that would be pretty insecure if it were possible. Your options are:

1. Remove the attribute from the methods you need to call.
2. Pass the correct security headers in the ajax call.
3. Modify the SecureAttribute class to allow OPTIONS method (but that sounds pretty insecure too)
4. Create new methods for ajax that don't have the attribute attached.

I'd suggest option 2.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the security headers in ajax. The problem is that, it cannot be retrieved on first call, because method is `OPTIONS` and `device` header is not included.

Comment: Then perhaps your first call could be to get the security headers?

Comment: hmmm.. Good idea. But for now, I don't know how to do that. I will try if I can get the header value inside `CORS attribute`.

Comment: BTW, how would you do the number 3? Can you give me some idea?

Comment: @fiberOptics Various ways. you could create another constructors that lets you pass in a list of methods that are not checked, then on functions that you need to exclude, pass those methods in. Inside the attribute code, do the check in there.

Comment: Please see my edit. It is working now. But do you think it's safe?

Comment: @fiberOptics I don't think so, it does mean that someone can call any method on your Api if they pass an Origin header and OPTIONS method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54041/discussion-between-davidg-and-fiberoptics).